# How do Google and Alexa determine their published scores?

Tags: seo, google-ranking, alexa-internet

In which way to Google and Alexa determine the rank of a site?

I have an account on Alexa, but it doesn't show any information because my site visitors are few (500-600 per day).

Google PageRank is always **0**.

I followed all standards of responsive design (for mobile and desktop), good keywords, w3c validations, cool articles, and backlinks.  Why does my website have the same rank as a plain white page would?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexa Rank is based on visitors and backlinks and it's not consider On-Page SEO.
Google Rank is calculated on both **Off-Page** and **On-Page** SEO (responsive design, page titles, descriptions, content and validations are relevant).
However, google rank is **very slow** to increase (in my experience); if your site is online from less than 1 year, don't worry.

Comment: Google page rank is calculation of links to your site (quantity/quality), that is all.

Answer (score 1):

Google Page rank and Alexa Ranking are completely different. Google page rank is the grade given for the quality of a site whereas Alexa ranking depends on the popularity of the website, the visitors to the website and so on.

SEO is as such a slow process but it is an effective one. Just continue doing your regular seo work without spamming and you would get a good rank in a long run. If you are an expert in SEO and are confident about what you are doing, go ahead. Else, I would suggest you to choose a professional SEO company like Integra Web Services, who may assist you to achieve good rankings.

Answer (score 1):

Google's PageRank as displayed by the Google Toolbar is a measure of the quality of your back links to a particular page.  Google doesn't update the data displayed by the toolbar very often.    The last time they updated the date was in December 2013.   If your page was created since then, it won't show any PageRank until the next data refresh from Google.

Google does internally calculate PageRank for their rankings every day.  So it is very possible for a page to show up in the search results while still showing PR 0.

Alexa calculates its rank to the site as a whole based on the number of users that site has.   Alexa gets its data about the number of users on a site primarily from people with the Alexa Toolbar installed.   There is very little advantage to having a better Alexa ranking other than bragging rights, so I would recommend not paying much attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

The alexa rank depends on high quality back links and your relationship

Answer (score 0):

The key to getting more search traffic is not just about building more links or adding more content. It is also about understanding Google’s algorithm.  So, if you want to maximize your search rankings, your best job is to do what is best for your users. Sure, in the short run your rankings may not climb as fast as you would like them to, but in the long run you will rank well

Comment: Please add some code or add a tag at least.